# A proof about field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra

If α ∈ E is algebraic over F and the minimal polynomial m(X) of α over F has degree
n, then F(α) = F[α], the set of polynomials in α with coefficients in F. In fact, F[α]
is the set $F_{n−1}[α]$ of all polynomials of degree at most n − 1 with coefficients in F, and 1, α, . . . , $α^{n−1}$ form a basis for the vector space F[α] over the field F. Consequently, [F(α) : F] = n.

**Proof**

> Let f(X) be any nonzero polynomial over F of degree n − 1 or less. Then since
>   m(X) is irreducible and deg f < deg m, f(X) and m(X) are relatively prime, and there are polynomials a(X) and b(X) over F such that a(X)f(X) + b(X)m(X) = 1. But
>   then a(α)f(α) = 1, so that any nonzero element of $F_{n−1}[α]$ has a multiplicative inverse. It follows that $F_{n−1}[α]$ is a field. (This may not be obvious, since the product of two polynomials of degree n−1 or less can have degree greater than n−1, but if deg g > n−1, then divide g by m to get g(X) = q(X)m(X) + r(X) where deg r(X) < degm(X) = n. Replace X by α to get g(α) = r(α) ∈ $F_{n−1}[α]$. Less abstractly, if m(α) = α3 +α+1 = 0, then α3 = −α − 1, α4 = −α2 − α, and so on.)
>
> Now any field containing F and α must contain all polynomials in α, in particular
>   all polynomials of degree at most n − 1. Therefore $F_{n−1}[α]$ ⊆ F[α] ⊆ F(α). But F(α)
>   is the smallest field containing F and α, so F(α) ⊆ $F_{n−1}[α]$, and we conclude that
>   F(α) = F[α] = $F_{n−1}[α]$. Finally, the elements 1, α, . . . , $α^{n−1}$ certainly span $F_{n−1}[α]$, and they are linearly independent because if a nontrivial linear combination of these elements were zero, we would have a nonzero polynomial of degree less than that of m(X) with α as a root, contradicting (2) of (3.1.6).
>
> (2) of (3.1.6) says "m(X) is the monic polynomial of least degree such that $m(\alpha)=0$.

I think I understood this proof, except for the last sentence...it's a bit confusing to me.

1) How/why do "the elements 1, α, . . . , $α^{n−1}$ certainly span $F_{n−1}[α]$"? I can't really see how, because the theorem is just telling us that these are elements of $F_{n-1}[\alpha]$, right? So how can we conclude they span all of that field?

2) When the proof says that " if a nontrivial linear combination of these elements were zero, we would have a nonzero polynomial of degree less than that of m(X)...". So when it says a linear combination, does it mean that we have $b_0 + b_1α + ... + b_{n-1}a^{n-1}$, where $b_0, ... ,b_{n-1}$ are functions with coefficients in F? (Of course of degree at most n-1)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any element of $F_{n-1}[\alpha]$ is of the form $b_0+b_1\alpha+\ldots+b_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}$ with $b_i\in F$, that is, a linear combination of $1,\alpha,\ldots,\alpha^{n-1}$. For 2), the coefficients $b_i$ are elements of $F$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is different than the one that I am familiar with (using the First Isomorphism Theorem), but in any case:

1) I take it that $F_{n-1}[\alpha]$ is the set of polynomials in $\alpha$ with degree at most $n-1$, and coefficients in $F$? Then that is exactly what it means for $1,\alpha,\dots,\alpha^{n-1}$ to be a basis for $F(\alpha)/F$, since $F(\alpha)=F_{n-1}[\alpha]=\lbrace a_0+a_1\alpha+\cdots+a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}:a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}\in F\rbrace$.

2) A linear combination means that the $b_i$ are elements of your base field $F$.

Comment: Thanks. But I thought that $F(\alpha) = \{ \frac{a_0+a_1\alpha+\cdots+a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}}{b_0+b_1\alpha+\cdots+b_{n-1} {\alpha}^{n-1}} :a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}, b_0, \dots, b_{n-1} \in F\}$.

Comment: It is (almost), $F(\alpha)=\lbrace\frac{f}{g}:f,g\in F[\alpha],g\ne 0\rbrace$: the denominator has to be non-zero. But If $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$, then it can be shown (as you've already said you were happy with that portion of the proof) that $F(\alpha)=F_{n-1}[\alpha]$. They are the same thing if $\alpha$ is algebraic. For example, $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. The element $\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}\in K$, but can be rewritten as $\sqrt{2}-1$. The point is that if $\alpha$ is algebraic, you don't need to worry about quotients of polynomials in $\alpha$, as the denominators can be cancelled.